# Overriding Object's Length Property

Tags: javascript

I found myself in an interesting situation. I am using an object literal to represent a product in the real-world. Now each product has a length associated to it for shipping purposes. It looks something like this:

```
var product = {
  name: 'MacBook Pro 15 Inch',
  description: 'The new macbook pros....',
  length: 15
  height: 15
  Weight: 4
}
```

This this works fine. But for products that have unknown length they default to length -1.

Again this works fine, until you try to do this:

```
console.log('Product has the following properties');
_.each(product, function(val, key) {
    console.log(key + ":" + val);
});
```

No keys will be printed for a product that has a length of `-1`. Why? Well because internally underscore uses the length attribute, that every object in Javascript has to loop over all the attributes of the passed in object. Since we overwrote that value, it is now `-1`, and since we start looping at `i = 0`, the loop will never be executed.

Now for the question, how can I prevent the length property from being overridden? Best practices to prevent this from happening would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    var product = {
        name: "MacBook Pro 15 Inch",
        description: 'The new macbook pros....',
        length: 15,
        height: 15,
        weight: 4
    };
    console.log('Product has the following properties');
    _.each(_.keys(product), function(key){
        console.log(key + ":" + product[key]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps due to some magic in `_`'s `each` function as I suspect it accepts both `Object`s and `Array`s .. make your own?

Simple implementation (that avoids some common pitfalls):

```
function each(obj, map_func) {
    var key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnerProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            map_func(key, obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

The magic in `_`'s `each` is probably due a nasty 'habit' in JavaScript of having things that 'look' like Arrays but aren't actually Arrays, like the magical variable `arguments`, and I think `options` in a select DOM Elements as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything off-hand that overrides it. I suppose using the length property is a form of duck typing that marks it by jQuery as iterable.

But.. you can just *not use* the jQuery each method, and do it the manual way..

By simply using

```
for (key in product) { 


}
```

You get your basic loop. Now if you are potentially overriding the object's prototype, you should also check product.hashOwnProperty(key) to make sure the current key you're iterating is defined in the product instance.

Now if you also need a new closure scope, that's pretty simple too.. here's an alternative each function..

```
var myEach = function(subject, callback) {

  for (key in subject) {

     if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        callback(subject[key], key);
     }
  }

}
```

Note: untested.

Comment: I would like to point out the 'pitfall' here that your object can override the property `hasOwnProperty`, so use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, which is the function you want.

Comment: underscore actually has a method just for that case `_.has()` that uses the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. But yeah thanks for the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the name of the length property, you could add an additional check to underscore to prevent this case:

```
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  if (obj == null) return;
  if (Array.prototype.forEach && obj.forEach === Array.prototype.forEach) {
    obj.forEach(iterator, context);
  } else if (obj.length === +obj.length && obj.constructor != Object) {
    for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  } else {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (_.has(obj, key)) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The addition here is the `&& obj.constructor != Object` on line 5. It works, though monkeypatching underscore may not be the most desirable thing in the world.

EDIT: Actually, this breaks on pseudo-arrays like `arguments`, since its constructor is `Object`, but `<an array-like object>.hasOwnProperty(<an integer>)` is false. Woo JavaScript.